# Quel mot français se rapprocherait de « apricity »?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Je cherche un mot de français ou d'ancien français, ou de français régional, pour traduire « apricity ».

« Apricity » a disparu (quasiment) de la langue anglaise moderne, mais réapparaît parfois.

Il est parfois défini comme « la chaleur du soleil », mais c'est une définition contestée, d'autres lui préfèrent une traduction qu'ils considèrent plus juste « la chaleur du soleil en plein hiver ».
Pour l'une ou l'autre des définitions, quelle serait le mot le plus proche en français ?

Comment: La chaleur du soleil, c'est déjà ce que j'ai mis dans la question, et ce n'est pas un mot.

Comment: Intéressante question. Je ne suis pas sûr qu'elle ait une réponse mais j'espère que oui car je trouve ca assez poétique comme mot, bien que difficile à placer quand-même :-)

Comment: À mon avis l'analyse débute en amont avec _sunshine_, c'est un seul mot qui en contient comme deux, et en français c'est le soleil, la lumière ou la lumière du soleil. J'ai réfléchi à l'exemple « As he stood in the sunshine, apricity began to cover him like a wool sweater. ». Dans un tel exemple on peut à mon avis distribuer les caractéristiques du soleil ou employer un possessif avec un nom pour la propriété _apricity_. C'est pas évident. Dans un exemple avec le verbe _to apricate_ duquel provient le nom, c'était la peau qui n'avait jamais été _exposée_ au soleil.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/winter-words

Answer (score 1):

Si j'en crois mes recherches, [apricity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricity) est le nom associé au verbe [apricate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricate) et viennent du latin [apricus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricus) qui signifie:

> 1. Découvert, exposé (au soleil)
> 2. Ensoleillé

Est-ce que le mot **exposition** pourrait convenir ou bien offrir des pistes pour une meilleure traduction?

Answer (score 0):

> Ardeur du soleil d’hiver.

Je pense

Comment: Il y a une source?

Answer (score 0):

Je ne connais pas de tel terme inusité en français pour la « [chaleur du soleil en hiver](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/winter-words) » et on n'a pas fourni de phrase ou de contexte. Voici un exemple produit en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40423/quel-mot-fran%C3%A7ais-se-rapprocherait-de-apricity#comment83213_40423) (qui change un peu la donne j'en conviens) :

> *As he stood in the sunshine, apricity began to cover him like a wool
> sweater.*
> Alors qu'il se tenait debout dans la lumière d'un soleil hivernal, une sensation [héliotherme](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/17076779/heliotherme) commença à l'[abrier](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/abrier#b944cdcbb6db6992) (couvrir, recouvrir) tel un chandail de laine.

L'adjectif [*héliotherme*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/17076779/heliotherme) peut signifier « dont la chaleur provient du soleil », entre autres, et l'aspect hivernal est étayé par la première partie de la phrase (sinon on devra dire « d'hiver, hivernal(e) »). Dans ce genre de contexte j'aurais tout simplement pu dire « sa chaleur ». On a aussi l'[*héliothermie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9liothermie) mais il s'agit d'une modalité de thermorégulation chez les animaux (Wikipédia).

Des termes en science basés sur le grec *hếlios* (soleil) et *thermós* (chaleur). On est loin d'une solution miracle et « sensation dont la chaleur provient du soleil » est un peu tordu mais c'est au moins aussi inusité qu'« *apricity* » !

Answer (score -1):

Un mot littéraire sera « ardeur » mais seulement dans « ardeur du soleil », c'est à dire qu'il ne peut pas constituer une définition du terme mais seulement une définition idiomatique de « chaleur » lorsqu'il s'agit du soleil (et de certaines autres entités). On peut aussi utiliser cette expression au pluriel : « les ardeurs du soleil ».

- Alors que les périodes de canicules ont tendance à se multiplier, tout bon jardinier doit dès à présent essayer de mieux connaître ces plantes qui, loin de craindre les ardeurs du soleil, se complaisent sous des rayons qui incommodent tant les autres. https://www.estrepublicain.fr/magazine-lifestyle/2019/07/20/decouvrez-ces-plantes-de-jardin-qui-adorent-le-soleil

Comme « ardeur » est un nom gradable on peut parler de la faible ardeur du soleil d'hiver, de la violente ardeur du soleil de midi en été.

Comment: "Ardeur" ne colle pas, enfin je pense, car "apricity" correspond à un soleil d'hiver, c'est une douce chaleur, dans tous les cas, pas un soleil qui tape.